# Get instagram full profile information without "Instagram Graph Api"

Tags: c#, facebook, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I wanna get some data from the Instagram users.

So I've used **Instagram Basic Display Api** and the profile data I could receive was these:

- username
- media count
- account type

but I want these data:

- username
- name
- media count
- Profile Image
- followers count
- following count

I don't know how can I have these data without **Instagram Graph API**(in any way) in c#?

Or is there any way to get these data with the `WebClient` class or anything like that?

**Update for @Eehab answer:** I use `RestClient` and `WebClient` in this example and both of them give the same result.

Now see `WebClient` example:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string page = client.DownloadString("https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1");
Console.WriteLine(page);
Console.ReadKey();
```

and see an image of this code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kmFi.jpg).

now see the result of the code above [here](https://file.io/cYXwfuXLU6LL)

I've also got, that this [link](https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1) is the only access for login users and I've been login into my Instagram account in chrome already, but I think `WebClient` needs to log in too.

### **Edit Through @Eehab answer:**

In this case for using this Url([https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/?__a=1)), we can't do it without Instagram logged-in browser profile. So we should log in to Instagram with selenium and use the logged-in cookies to use it for Url requests. So first Install the selenium web driver and then write the following codes(untested):

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();

//go to Instagram
driver.Url = "https://www.instagram.com/";

//Log in
var userNameElement = _driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
userNameElement.SendKeys("Username");
var passwordElement = _driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
passwordElement.SendKeys(Cars[0].auth.pass);
var loginButton = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("login"));
loginButton.Click();

//Get cookies
var cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies.ToList();

//Send request with given cookies :)
var url = "https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1";
var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
foreach(var cookie in cookies){
   httpRequest.Headers["Cookie"] += $"{cookie.Name}={cookie.Value}; ";
}
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
   var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
//...
```

If anyone can improve this question for more uses can edit and I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using the open API , example :

https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1

example code from postman code :

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

you could use HttpClient class also, if you want to use WebClient you could do it with
WebClient.DownloadString Method while I don't recommend using WebClient for this scraping, keep in mind Instagram may block you if blocked you , you need residential proxies to bypass the block.

the response will be json data , use Json.Net or similar library to deserialize it.

just replace instagram with any username you want in the given url.

Comment: hi, thank you for your solution. when i go to this [URL](https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1) it give me a full user information with Json but when I request it by your code or `WebClient` or post man application it give me a useless html.

Comment: I just tested and worked ! , did you used same IP for both browsing and code request?

Comment: @Ehab yes my IP is same for both. I think this URL has preload JavaScript and must load before execute. Are you sure you test it right now and working fine?

Comment: This is not javascript rendering! This is json data you could get in pure socket request, show me your code of the webclient and I will test it on my machine.

Comment: `var client = new RestClient("https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);` this is your code and when I `WriteLine` `response.Content` it show me html file instead of json. and this is image of that html : https://imgur.com/kwaAEik

Comment: I said show me your WebClient code with download string method, please post it. The restsharp code not retrieving the page content actually..

Comment: WebClient client = new WebClient();
          
 var page = client.DownloadString("https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1");

Comment: I tested this code: WebClient client = new WebClient(); var page = client.DownloadString("instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1");  and it's working on my machine if it's not working you have problem from your side.

Comment: I have noticed that when I'm logged-in to instagram, this particular endpoint will return a json. When I'm not it will redirect to a login page. @Eehab does it work for you from a private tab?

Comment: Instagram started doing that to block scraping,  either include your login cookies in the http request or use high quality residential proxy to avoid blocking and get the json response.

Comment: "instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1" returns latest 12 timeline posts. Is there any way to retrieve more time posts ?

Comment: Yes, you need to look to the "has_next_page" value if it's true , find the "end_cursor" value and implement it in your request again for the next page and so, to find the right URL pattern to send the request install any HTTP plugin like "HTTP Live Header" and capture from your browser, this is how your browser load more posts... just simulate it in your requests.